# Mongodb is query is too slow for partial field search on the indexed fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have following mongodb document with 800 millions documents.

```
Customer
  {
   "lastName" : "LAST",
   "firstName" : "FIRST"
  }
```

I have following index

```
db.customer.createIndex( {lastName: 1, firstName: 1},{collation: { locale: "en_US", strength: 1}})
```

If I do search based on lastName and firstName, then its fast and getting result with in 10 ms.

```
 db.customer.find({lastName:"LAST" ,firstName:"FIRST"}).collation({ locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })
```

I am trying to find all documents that "AS" as the characters in the last name. But its taking more than 100 seconds to return the response. I tried following options but all taking more than 100 seconds. 
Does mongoDB really does like sql kind of like operation `('%AS%')`

**1)**

```
db.customer.find({lastName:{"$regex": "AS"} ,firstName:"FIRST"}).collation({ locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })
```

**2)**

```
db.customer.find({lastName:{"$regex": "/AS/"} ,firstName:"FIRST"}).collation({ locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })
```

**3)**

```
db.customer.find({lastName:{"$regex": "^/AS/"} ,firstName:"FIRST"}).collation({ locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

try use prefix on your regex to allow MongoDB use range

```js
db.customer.find({lastName:{"$regex": "/^AS/"} ,firstName:"FIRST"}).collation({ locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })
```

> A regular expression is a “prefix expression” if it starts with a caret (^) or a left anchor (\A), followed by a string of simple symbols. For example, the regex /^abc.*/ will be optimized by matching only against the values from the index that start with abc.
>   Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

[regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use)

Comment: hi, Your suggestion is same query as like in my original post(case 3). Its taking same 100 seconds.

Comment: well i put the hut ^ inside the pattern you put it outside. anyway if this doesn`t helps try create different index for each filed and not combine the index